# Accessing an enum from within a class, both of which are in the same namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, scope

I have something resembling the following setup:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    enum MyEnum{
        Type1,
        Type2
    };

    class MyClass
    {
        private:
            void MyFunction( MyEnum::Type1 );
    };
}
```

I would have assumed that since both `MyEnum` and `MyClass` are within `MyNAmespace`, using the enumerated types within the class wouldn't be a problem, but when I try to compile it I get the following error:

```
'MyEnum::Type1' is not a type
```

How can I fix this so I can use my enum and class in the same namespace?

Comment: `MyEnum::Type1` is an enum value, not a type, as your compiler is saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyEnum` is how you would reference it.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    enum MyEnum{
        Type1,
        Type2
    };

    class MyClass
    {
        private:
            void MyFunction( MyEnum );
    };
}
```

where the definition might look like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
  void MyClass::MyFunction( MyEnum val) {
    if (val == Type1)
      std::cout << "Type1" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`MyEnum::Type1` is *not* a type. It is a value. Try this:

```
void MyFunction( MyEnum );
```

Answer (score -1):

Typedef your enum

```
typedef enum _MyEnum{ Type1, Typ2}MyEnum;
```

Comment: This is totally not necessary in C++ *and* `_MyEnum` is a reserved name.

Comment: Yeah i completly mixed up things. I mixed up with adding enum in class to access through class, like: `MyClass::Type1`. Sorry